# Like somebody to do /doing something

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

> Nobody likes his friends to take advantage of him.
> (A New English Grammar, by Zhang Zhenbang, page 373)

Can I use "taking" instead of "to take" in the above sentence?

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions here about the difference between the ing-form and the to-infinitive. Basically the former is more likely to mean continuous action happening currently or for an extended period of time, and the latter to refer to the fact or consequences of an action. If you like going home you enjoy the journey, if you like to go home you enjoy being at home.